# Selenium ChromeDriver getting slow after some time

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web scrapper which is using Selenium Chrome Driver. Driver is created once and it opens different urls inside infinite loop. What I’ve noticed that after some time page loading gets slower and slower until I restart my application. Is there anything that I’m not aware of? Should I re-create driver from time to time to clear something?

Comment: scrapper implies that you are storing something, so check those routines to see if you have arrays that are getting larger, infinitely.

Comment: No, I don't have such arrays. I see that browser memory usage get higher after some time.

Comment: re-creating the driver oughta fix that.  Be sure to include a sleep after quitting one driver and beginning a new one.  (...give the browser time to clean up when it shuts down)